# Al detener la depuración de la página web en Visual Studio 2017 se cierra el navegador

Tags: visual-studio, web

Al detener la depuración de la página web en *Visual Studio 2017* se cierra el navegador.

Por ejemplo, en *VS 2015* tú depuras y se abre una pestaña en el navegador con tu página y si detienes la depuración el navegador no se cierra, pero en *VS 2017* se abre otra ventana del navegador, y si detengo la depuración se cierra el navegador sin importar que tenga otras pestañas abiertas. He buscado alguna configuración, pero nada. ¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 5):

Quitalos el check que biene activado!! [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola WILGOP, te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio). ¿Podrías añadir un poco más de información sobre esta solución? Parecería que realmente no hace lo que se busca (evitar cerrar la ventana al terminar depuración) sino algo parecido (terminar depuración al cerrar la ventana).

Answer (score 2):

Prueba configurar esto:

Herramientas -> Opciones -> Depuración -> General -> Enable JavaScript Debugging for ASP.NET (Chrome and IE).

Si tiene el check quitaselo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que ese es el comportamiento habitual. Quizás puedas utilizar **attach to process** y seleccionar el proceso de *IIS*. Lo reconocerás por el nombre **w3wp.exe**. Finalmente cuando ya no quieras seguir depurando solo libera los procesos (en el menú *debug* busca **detach All**).

Comment: Muchas gracias ArtEze. Aunque no creo que sea un comportamiento 
 habitual. E trabajado con vs 2010, 2012, 2013, 2015 y nunca me ha pasado